# Add pipe delimiter at the end of each line total number of pipes should be 11 in unix

Tags: unix, scripting

My file is as below

**ABC|DEFG|HIJKLM|NOP|QRSTUVW**

**12345|678|9102|345678|9|1023|45**

**Hello|world|This is|for testing the|pipe adding**

I would like to get the result as below (Total number of pipes should be 11 for each line)

**ABC|DEFG|HIJKLM|NOP|QRSTUVW|||||||**

**12345|678|9102|345678|9|1023|45|||||**

**Hello|world|This is|for testing the|pipe adding|||||||**

Basically each line should get appended with | at the end if total number of pipes for that line is not 11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the [grymoire's awk tutorial](https://grimoire.com/Unix/Awk.html), read up on `for` loops, `NF` variable and update your Q with best attempt to solve your problem. Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service, OK? ;-) Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: AND, use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: The link to http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html was wrong, it said `... grimoire...`.

Comment: You can also try `sed`: first add 11 pipes at the end, and then match with eleven blocks with (0-or-more non pipes chars followed by a pipe), and delete the remaining pipes.

Comment: Using a while loop, counting the pipes in each line and add those missing, should work as well but will be a lot slower.

Comment: @WalterA : Oops, I usually clck thru to make sure I have the correct URL. Thanks for the correction, and I'll try to dbl-check links consistently as I post them. Good luck to all!